# How to add comment for custom category attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, category, attributes, custom

i created a custom attribute for a category and want to add a comment on this attribute

[image]

how to add comment for costume attribute ?

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'externallink',  array(
'type'     => 'varchar', /* Type - see eav_entity_* for the different types */
'label'    => 'External Link Url', /* Your label */
'input'    => 'text', /* This refers to the type of form field should display*/
'global'   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
'visible'           => TRUE,
'required'          => FALSE,
'user_defined'      => FALSE,
'default'           => ''
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a `note` element in the config array

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'externallink',  array(
    'type'     => 'varchar', /* Type - see eav_entity_* for the different types */
    'label'    => 'External Link Url', /* Your label */
    'input'    => 'text', /* This refers to the type of form field should display*/
    'global'   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'           => TRUE,
    'required'          => FALSE,
    'user_defined'      => FALSE,
    'default'           => '',
    'note'              => 'YOUR COMMENT HERE' //add this line
));
```